Alternative ways to calculate Krull dimension of a particular ring
Let $R$ be the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at a prime $p$ and let $A = R[X,Y] / (XY^2 + p)$. I would like to calculate the Krull dimension of $A$

I have managed to get an idea on how to determin the dimension in the following way.
I have determined fully Spec$(R[X,Y])$ studying the fibers of the only two primes ($(0)$ and $(p)$) of $R$ considering the map
$$i^* : \mbox{ Spec}(R[X,Y]) \longrightarrow \mbox{ Spec}(R)$$
induced by
$$i : R \hookrightarrow R[X,Y] .$$
I have explicited the maximal chains of prime ideals which give a Krull dimension of $3$ for $R[X,Y]$, so that $A$ has at most dimension $2$, and finally explicited a chain that reaches dimension $2$.

I would like to know if there are any simpler ways of determining it's dimension without having to pass through the fiber study considered above, since it heavily relies on further full examination of Spec$(\mathbb{Q}[X,Y])$ and Spec$(\mathbb{F}_p [X,Y])$.

From your previous question we know that $A$ is an integral domain, meaning $0$ is a prime ideal. Moreover, we have the chain of prime ideals $0 \subseteq (X) \subseteq (X,Y)$ in $A$. To see that they are prime ideals, strictly contained in another, just compute the quotient rings.
So the dimension is at least $2$. It cannot be more than that: Otherwise the preimage in $R[X,Y]$ was a prime ideal chain of length more than $3$ (ideal correspondence theorem). Since $R$ is Noetherian and of dimension $1$, we have $\dim R[X,Y] = 2 + \dim R = 3$.

Would it be sufficient to show the following?$$\frac{A}{(X)} \cong \frac{R[X,Y]}{(X,p)} \cong \frac{R[Y]}{(p)} \cong (R/(p))[Y]$$where $(p)$ is prime in $R$, hence $R/(p)$ is a domain, hence $(R/(p))[Y]$ is a domain, too. And $$\frac{A}{(X,Y)} \cong \frac{R[X,Y]}{(X,Y,p)} \cong \frac{R}{(p)}$$ which is a domain as said above.

And, they are strictly contained in one another because the quotients are not isomorphic?

I would encourage you to get some confidence in your proofs by really analyzing every step till you are convinced 100% without asking others for approval.
